# Inicializar lista para sumar valores dentro un ciclo FOR

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

El código es el siguiente:

```
dict_enero={} #diccionario                
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for i in lista:
    monto=self.obtener_mes_cliente(i, linea[0]) #la funcion esta corecta
    dict_enero[i]+=monto
```

El error que devuelve es el siguiente:

```
dict_enero[i]+=monto KeyError: 1
```

Comment: No termino de entender exactamente tu planteo, podrías dar un poco más de info? Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres almacenar los valores que el método te devuelve, entonces un [diccionario](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) no es la estructura de datos que necesitas. Cada elemento de un diccionario es un par `key : value` (indice : valor). Si solo vas a almacenar cada valor retornado, usar listas `[]` y para añadirlo a ella: `lista_enero.append(monto)`. Si quieres sumar todo, al final le puedes hacer un `sum(lista_enero)`

Comment: me lo podrias poner en codigo como se veria porfavor amigo

Comment: `dict_enero = collections.defaultdict(int)` y ya se inicializa el solo con 0 cuando accedes a una clave inexistente. Es decir, tu código ya funcionaría.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en que haces referencia a una clave (key), del diccionario que aun no existe en la línea:

```py
dict_enero[i] += monto
```

Esta linea equivale a:

```py
dict_enero[i] = dict_enero[i] + monto
```

Que quiere decir en `dict_enero[i]` ponga lo que tiene `dict_enero[i]`, pero esa clave no existe, se debe inicializar el diccionario y luego modificarlo:

```py
dict_enero={} #diccionario                
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for i in lista:
    dict_enero[i] = 0 #inicializas el diccionario para que las llaves existan
    monto=200 #la funcion esta corecta
    dict_enero[i]+=monto
print(dict_enero)
```